# Ionic 4+ Angular: search-icon in ion-searchbar and toolbar is misaligned with onfocus-event

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, alignment, toolbar, searchbar

I put the ion-searchbar in my ion-toolbar. Everything looks fine until you click into the searchbar and the method (ionFocus)="onFocus()" is activated. Because then, the buttons in the toolbar disappear and the search bar gets the full width, **whereby the search icon does not move to the left but stays in place.** (picture 2)

As soon as you type something into the search bar, the search icon positions itself to the left at the correct place, as you can see in the last third picture.

If I don't use the (ionFocus) method, the search icon is moved correctly. However, I need the (ionFocus) method and I am forced to find a solution.

I am grateful for any help!

```
<ion-searchbar 
  placeholder="Suche im Wiki" 
  inputmode="text" type="text" 
  [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" mode="ios"
  (ionChange)="onSearchChange($event)" 
  (ionCancel)="cancelSearch()" 
  (ionBlur)="onBlur()" 
  (ionFocus)="onFokus()"
  showCancelButton="focus" 
  [debounce]="250" 
  animated="true">
</ion-searchbar>
```

Picture 1: Default look

Picture 2: This is what the toolbar looks like when I clicked in the search bar.

Picture 3: This is what the toolbar looks like when I type something into the search bar. You can see that as soon as you type something, the search icon moves to the left to the correct position.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you tell why ionFocus? Can't you exchange for example with (click)="onFokus()" ?

Comment: When I use (click)="onFocus()", the problem arises that (onBlur)="...()" does not work properly.

Comment: Can you expain to you want to do exactly since maybe we can solve your problem without ionFocus and ionBlur

Comment: When clicking into the searchbar I want to hide the two buttons (left and right of the searchbar) in the toolbar and finally get the searchbar in full width (as shown in the bottom picture). Thereby the enlargement of the searchbar should be minimized. 

As soon as I leave the searchbar, the buttons should be shown again and the searchbar should return to its previous size, as shown in the first picture.

Comment: Last question before i give my answer, on the part of leaving the searchbar and returning to the default sate, the user clicks cancel or press or swipe down(blur action)?

Comment: Yes, click on cancel or press on page, ..

Answer (score 1):

Here we go mate:
in the ts file ad these:

```
defaultBar:boolean=false;
```

And then add these 2 methods :

```
hideDefaultBar(){
  this.defaultBar =false;
}

showDefaultBar(){
  this.defaultBar =true;
  this.searchTerm = "";
}
```

Now in the html part:

In the first state of bar with the 2 icons beside add in its container this:

```
*ngIf="defaultBar == true"
```

And inside it this:

```
<ion-searchbar 
  placeholder="Suche im Wiki" 
  mode="ios"
  (click)="hideDefaultBar()">
</ion-searchbar>
```

And the second container you will add these:

```
<ion-searchbar 
  *ngIf="defaultBar == false"
  placeholder="Suche im Wiki" 
  inputmode="text" type="text" 
  [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" mode="ios"
  (ionChange)="onSearchChange($event)" 
  (ionCancel)="showDefaultBar()" 
  (ionBlur)="showDefaultBar()"
  showCancelButton="always" 
  [debounce]="250" 
  animated="true">
</ion-searchbar>
```

Test it and tell me if anyproblem exists.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your effort! I will try to implement your solution as soon as I get to the office.

Comment: I'm afraid not. As with my attempt, there is the problem of not recognizing that the search bar is focused. When clicking into the search bar, the buttons disappear as desired and the search bar gets the full width. But the Cancel button does not appear.

Comment: Sinnce there is no ionFocus()?

Comment: Set the focus to always

Comment: showCancelButton="always" , and that should solve .